# In Glitch, how can I see quickly how many skills I have learned?

Tags: glitch-2011

In Glitch, you can only learn X skills before "brain detoriation" kicks in, making it take longer. Without counting them manually, how do I know how many I have learned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by [Yi Jiang's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34025/in-glitch-how-can-i-see-quickly-how-many-skills-i-have-learned/34042#34042), I've created [scripts for your browser](http://db.tt/3zDTtBGQ) which embed skill counts into Glitch's own skills pages:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: oh no! the image is not there :(

Comment: @fireDude67 — Fixed.  Dropbox is blocked at work so I'd had to copy the URL from my phone.  Must have mistyped it.  :-)

Answer (score 10):

There's no direct way to do this, as fredley mentioned, but there are a few 'interesting' ways to do this.

1. Go to your profile page, look at the list of Latest Skills. It should look something like this:

   [image: Glitch profile latest skills screenshot]

   Take the number you see on the right, then add up the number of icons displayed in the list.
2. Go to your skills page, then pop open your browser's console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> on Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on Chrome), and type in:

   ```
   $('li.got').length
   ```

   The number of learned skills should show up in the console

Comment: I've created [bookmarklet and userscript versions](http://db.tt/3zDTtBGQ) of the second method.

Comment: If @BenBlank that was an answer I would accept it. But its not :(

Comment: @fireDude67 — As you wish!  :-)

Answer (score 6):

I have put together a tiny app with the API:

## [Glitch Skill Checker](http://www.tommedley.com/glitch/)

This will tell you how many skills you have learned, your current Better Learning level, and use this information to tell you your bonus/penalty to learn your next skill.

Answer (score 5):

I've actually created a tool for doing this, called the Skillifier:

http://agent86.nfshost.com/glitch/

Not only does it tell you what you've learned, it shows you all the skills left and how much time it will take to learn each one in order.  It shows the penalty percentage as well.  In fact, it even shows a simple, "greedy" algorithm method of selecting the next skill, if time ordering is your priority.  It also lets you prioritize skills that you'd prefer to learn early, and tracks prerequisites.